# PHP form not submitting until all the info entered

Tags: php, mysql

I am submitting an HTML form using php and I have these fields in my form:

- Name:(varchar)
- Address:(varchar)
- FAX:(int)
- PHONE:(int)
- EMAIL:(varchar)
- plus a primary ID that gets added on its own.

Now my form doesn't get submitted until I enter the fax field? Does anyone know why is it happening?

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Strict//EN"
  "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-strict.dtd">

<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" lang="en" xml:lang="en">

<body>

<?php

require_once('../../public_html/input.php');

require_once('../../public_html/nauth.php');

require_once('../../public_html/mysql.php');



if (isset($_GET['more']))

{ 

    $more = $_GET['more'];

    $new = 8;

}

if (isset($_POST['submit']))

{

    $more = 4;

    $new = 8;

    $name = $_SESSION['username'];

    $dbc = mysqli_connect(cname, chost, cpwd, cdb);

    $com_name = mysqli_real_escape_string($dbc, trim($_POST['com_name']));

    $com_address = mysqli_real_escape_string($dbc, trim($_POST['com_address']));

    $com_phone = mysqli_real_escape_string($dbc, trim($_POST['com_phone']));

    $com_fax = mysqli_real_escape_string($dbc, trim($_POST['com_fax']));

    $source_id = $_POST['source'];



    $com_email = mysqli_real_escape_string($dbc, trim($_POST['com_email']));

    $entered_by = $name;

    $query = "select * from company_customers where name='$com_name'";

    $data = mysqli_query($dbc, $query);



    if (mysqli_num_rows($data) == 0) //to check if the name already exists

    {

        $query="insert into  company_customers(name,address,phone,fax,email,entered_by,source_id) values('$com_name','$com_address','$com_phone','$com_fax','$com_email','$entered_by','$source_id')";

        mysqli_query($dbc, $query);

        $query = "select * from company_customers where name='$com_name'";

        $data = mysqli_query($dbc, $query);

        $row = mysqli_fetch_array($data);

        $id = $row['id']; //to add the company id in the contacts table

        $i = 0;

        while (!empty($_POST['name' . $i]))

        {   

            $name = $_POST['name' . $i];

            $designation = $_POST['desig' . $i];

            $phone = $_POST['phone' . $i];

            $query = "insert into contacts(name,designation,id,phone) values('$name','$designation','$id','$phone')";

            mysqli_query($dbc, $query);

            $i++;

        }

        mysqli_close($dbc);

        echo 'Added';

        require_once('option.php');

        exit();

    }

    else echo 'company already entered';

}

else if (isset($_POST['more']))

{

    $more = $_POST['count'];

    $new = $more + 4;

}

?>

<form action="<?php echo $_SERVER['PHP_SELF']; ?>" method="POST">

<fieldset><legend>Company Profile</legend>

<label for="com_name">Company Name:</label><input type="text" name="com_name" value="<?php if(isset($_POST['more'])) echo $_POST['com_name']; ?>"/><br />

<label for="com_address">Company Address:</label><input type="text" name="com_address"     value="<?php if(isset($_POST['more'])) echo $_POST['com_address']; ?>" /><br />

<label for="com_phone">Company Phone:</label><input type="text" name="com_phone" value="<?php if(isset($_POST['more'])) echo $_POST['com_phone']; ?>" /><br />

<label for="com_fax">Company Fax:</label><input type="text" name="com_fax" value="<?php if(isset($_POST['more'])) echo $_POST['com_fax']; ?>" /><br />

<label for="com_email">Company Email:</label><input type="text" name="com_email" value="<?php if(isset($_POST['more'])) echo $_POST['email']; ?>" /><br />

<?php

$dbc = mysqli_connect(cname, chost, cpwd, cdb);

$query = "select * from source";

$data = mysqli_query($dbc, $query);

$number_row = mysqli_num_rows($data);

$source[0] = '';

$source_id[0] = ''; 

$i = 1;

while ($row = mysqli_fetch_array($data))

{ 

    $source[$i] = $row['src'];

    $source_id[$i] = $row['source_id'];

    $i++;

}

echo '<label for="source">Source</label><select name="source">';

for ($i = 0; $i <= $number_row; $i++)

    echo '<option value="' . $source_id[$i] . '">' . $source[$i] . '</option>';

echo '</select>';

?>

</fieldset>

<fieldset><legend>Company Contact</legend>

<?php

for ($i = 0; $i < $more; $i++)

{ 

?>

<label for="<?php echo 'name' . $i; ?>">Name:</label><input type="text" name="<?php echo  'name' . $i; ?>" value="<?php if (isset($_POST['more'])) echo $_POST['name' . $i]; ?>" />

<label for="<?php echo 'desig' . $i; ?>">Designation:</label><input type="text" name="<?php echo 'desig' . $i; ?>" value="<?php if (isset($_POST['more'])) echo   $_POST['desig' . $i];?>" />

<label for="<?php echo 'phone' . $i;?>">Phone:</label><input type="text" name="<?php  echo 'phone' . $i;?>" value="<?php if (isset($_POST['more'])) echo $_POST['phone' . $i]; ?>" /><br />

<?php

}

?>

<input type="hidden" name="count" value="<?php echo $new; ?>" />

<input type="submit" name="more" value="more" />

</fieldset>

<input type="submit" name="submit" value="ADD" />

</form>

</body>

</html>
```

Comment: can you post the HTML version of your form, and the php function that handles the submission?

Comment: nope.  we won't anything unless we see some code.  did you copy/paste some code that included (client-side/JS) validation in it?

Comment: show us the code to know the answer

Comment: If you want to require all fields to filled out except for the fax I'd check your required field section of the code and make sure you didn't include the fax field into it on accident. Really outside of that no one can do much if you don't post any code. That tiny bit isn't going to help us. We need the html form and the php code that handles the submission.

Comment: If what you are saying ("form doesn't get submitted") is true, then this has nothing to do with php and mysql. show us the (generated) HTML.

Comment: someone kindly format the edits please! i am not able to do it completeley.

Comment: in my data base only fax is integer type rest all are varchar,except for id that is tinyint.

Comment: until i dont enter the fax field it does not submit, i guess is it something that all the integer fields have to be filled in compulsarily??

Comment: @Karan: I submitted an edit for peer review, once it gets approved, could you take a look and make sure it's still your code? I put in some spaces for legibility (it might improve your chances of help), but I took care that it's still functionally the same thing - still, I'd feel better if you gave it a review.

Comment: @pinkgothic yeah,i guess its the same code! can you tell me why i am unable to submit it?

Answer (score 1):

Try setting the column to allow `null` values in mysql. E.g.

```
ALTER TABLE company_customers CHANGE fax fax INT(11) NULL
```

Comment: @Karan, maybe you could post the column information to rule out issues of this sort. `SHOW COLUMNS FROM company_customers`